# Accessing the value of variable that is changed in a change method outside of the change method?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, onchange

I tried asking this type of question before, but I don't understand if what I want to do is possible. When things change like when a select dropdown is changed or checkbox is checked or unchecked is it possible to put those values in a global variable so I could use those values later in the code
    for example I want do something like this

```
var amountChosen;

$('#amountItems').change(function(){
            amountchosen = $('#amountItems option:selected').val();
            alert(amountchosen)
});
```

So I want the value of amountChosen to change in side the change method because that's how I know it to work but i wont that to apply to the global variable.

Because I want do something like this deep inside another function

```
if(amountChosen == 2){
    do this
}
if(amountChosen == 3){
    do this
}
etc.
```

I could never get the value outside of the change method which is a big problem.

If I have some place in my code, a part where I need to pull in information like the user checked this and the amount of items he chose. As far as I know I would have to do all that in a .change method or .is('checked'). How do I make the variable that are changed usable in a parameter of a function that is far away from the code.

To sum it up. I got different functions doing different thing depending on states (I guess its called that). I have problems getting the updated states in functions so i could make actions depending on the state

Comment: i  know thanks . but that's not my issue right now. I didn't make that mistake in my app im trying to make. i just made that mistake here while trying to explain my problem. ill change it. I guess my question might about code structure

Comment: Post running code (as `Code Snippet`) that shows your problem.

Comment: Sounds like a scoping issue, can you show us the code with this "deep function"

Comment: this is what I was working on before. if yo go to the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ot38Lz70/3/ and go to the part below the //if i take this code out of the click event it wont work comment. it won't work. you'll see that i cant use the withones variable outside of the click event. let say I wanted to use the value of withones to show checked or unchecked somewhere else. basically  I would like for you to show me how to use the updated withones outside of the click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to explore using an event emitter, or pub-sub system. Since you are already using jQuery, it's easy to create our own emitter.

```
$emitter = $({});

function foo() {
  $('#amountItems').change(function(){
    var amountchosen = $('#amountItems option:selected').val();
    $emitter.trigger('amountUpdate', amountchosen);
  });
}

function bar() {
  $emitter.on('amountUpdate', function(e, amount){
    // do something with the amount
  });
}
```

This puts you in the same situation where both functions need to have the event emitter within their scope, but the emitter can be a channel for many uncoupled or loosely coupled components to talk with each other.

Comment: using the trigger from http://api.jquery.com/trigger/  ? your creating an eventType called amountUpdate that has the updated vals. then your using the event type in the on method of the obj?  I didn't think I would have to do something this advanced. this looks interesting. I never did this before. thanks for your reply.

Comment: Sounds like you understand it.  It's a common pattern, and you are already familiar with it for jQuery, as triggering and subscribing to custom events use the same API as DOM events.

Comment: sorry to bother you but I am having trouble implementing this. I'm still a novice. I dont know how/where to call these function view jsfiddle --http://jsfiddle.net/ob2bybcq/ I guess I want to be able to do something in the  bar function like if(amount == 3) alert(3). I just cant get a simple console.log out. If you could get back to me at your earlier convenience that would be great

Comment: I like @Jack's solution, because it is very clean/a best practice for this use case: it doesn't pollute global scope, while accomplishing precisely what you are looking to achieve, nothing more nothing less, with no side effects. [PubSub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern) is a very common pattern.

[Here's it is in a separate gist](https://gist.github.com/addyosmani/1321768#option-2-custom-events-using-on-and-off), which lists some other variations of implementing this same pattern.

Comment: @jack thanks for your help but im still having problems understanding how  to separate events so I could get their  results in an object type of things. I put up a question with more details. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28332651/trying-to-change-an-object-with-pubsub-pattern-or-through-a-function .. if you could answer that when you get a chance, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything special: if you use a variable that is defined "outside" the scope of a function, a closure is created and the function will keep a reference to the variable. So many functions can have a reference to the same variable.

For instance very high in your code (like in the global level):

```
// At the top of your main file.js
var myVar = initialValue;

// somewhere deeper into the code (getter)
function one() {
  if (myVar === something) { ... }
}

// Somewhere else like from another file (setter)
function two() {
  myVar = something;
}
```

If you do not have access to myVar into one of these functions, it mean you didn't declare myVar high enough. When I say "high", I'm thinking about the scope hierarchy:

```
// global level, very high
var rootVariable;

function toto() {
  // toto level, has access to rootVariable
  var totoVar;
}

function tutu() {
  // tutu level, has access to rootVariable but not totoVar
  var tutuVar;
}
```

If I misunderstood your problem or that still doesn't work, please try to create a jsfiddle that reproduces your issue.

Answer (score -1):

A very trivial solution would be to simply save the value somewhere and then look it up later:

```
<input type="text" id="amountItems" data-amount-chosen="0">

$('#amountItems').change(function(){
    amountchosen = $('#amountItems option:selected').val();
    $('#amountItems').data("amount-chosen", amountchosen);
    alert(amountchosen);
});

// somewhere later...
var amountchosen = $('#amountItems').data("amount-chosen");
if(amountChosen == 2){
    do this
}
if(amountChosen == 3){
    do this
}
etc.
```

Note that we simply changed the html tag to add a data element, saved the correct data there, and then looked it up again later when we needed it.

Comment: I didnt test this yet. but im looking at the first line `<input type="text" id="amountItems" data-amount-chosen="0">`do i need to have the `data-amount-chosen` here im using select box. would i have to do this `<select name="" id="amountItems" data-amount-chosen="0">` instead of  `<select name="" id="amountItems" >`

Comment: Yes you can add a data element to most types of elements

Comment: hello I believe I tried to implement what you told me but the amountChosen does not seem to test right. you could see it in the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/L4oamm2s/ . when I change to 2 in the select box i get no alert. it should say "amount 2 was chosen"

Comment: do you see the problem?